# Not able to connect multiple appium node to selenium grid

Tags: node.js, selenium, command-line, automation, appium

I want to run appium scripts in parallel on multiple devices but always the second node fails to connect to the selenium server.

This is my selenium server logs which starts and registers perfectly

```
D:\Appium>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -port 4444 -role hub m
axInstances=2 maxSession=2 -timeout 30000
15:17:45.215 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2016-02-25 15:17:45.810:INFO::main: Logging initialized @732ms
15:17:45.818 INFO - Will listen on 4444
15:17:45.856 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2016-02-25 15:17:45.859:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
2016-02-25 15:17:45.879:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletC
ontextHandler@b0ed20{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2016-02-25 15:17:45.893:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@
76c8cd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2016-02-25 15:17:45.894:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @816ms
15:17:45.894 INFO - Nodes should register to http://10.51.25.88:4444/grid/regist
er/
15:17:45.894 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
15:18:13.259 INFO - Registered a node http://10.51.25.88:4724
15:18:25.289 INFO - Marking the node http://10.51.25.88:4724 as down: cannot rea
ch the node for 2 tries
```

This is my Json file to create node and set capabilites

```
{"capabilities":[{"deviceName":"0009aec74c7a5f","browserName":"chrome","maxInstances":1,"version":"4.1.2","platform":"ANDROID"}],"configuration":{"proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","cleanUpCycle":2000,"port":4724,"host":"10.51.25.88","maxSession":1,"hubHost":"10.51.25.88","registerCycle":5000,"hubPort":4444,"timeout":30000,"url":"http:\/\/10.51.25.88:4724\/wd\/hub","register":true}}
```

Hence in the similar way when I try to connect my second appium node it fails to register in appium grid without any command prompt error logs

I have two physical devices connected through USB and devices detected through adb.I am using the latest version of Appium 1.4 and the latest selenium standalone server jar file 2.52.

I am able to register my appium node to selenium server for every first node , either of the device , but when I try to connect my second appium node It fails to connect closing the command promt without giving any error logs.

This same commands and configuration used to work for previous version of Appium (about one year Old), but for the new Appium version second node is not getting registered.

Is there any alternative method to register appium node to selenium grid , or Is there something I am missing above ?

Answer (score 0):

I have built library that generates .json and .bat file for each Appium node. It is tested well and work so cool. So I believe you are missing boot strapping port number to connect another instance of Appium.

Json File:

```
{
"capabilities":
[
{
"DeviceManufacturer":"LGE",
"DeviceModel":"Nexus 5",
"DeviceOS":"Android",
"OSVersion":"6.0.1",
"DeviceType":"Real",
"deviceName":"038d1797094778a8",
"browserName":"Real_LGE_Nexus 5_Android_6.0.1",
"platform":"Android"
}],
"configuration":
{
"nodeTimeout":120,
"port":4723,
"hubPort":4444,
"proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
"url":"http://192.168.1.246:4723/wd/hub",
"hub": "192.168.1.246:4444/grid/register",
"hubHost":"192.168.1.246",
"nodePolling":2000,
"registerCycle":10000,
"register":true,
"cleanUpCycle":2000,
"timeout":30000,
"maxSession":5
}
}
```

You must be observing that I am using multiple capabilities but I am using all of them by overriding matches method of org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher class. so when I call main method of org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher class. I am keeping my overriding jar in same class path and It worked for customizing matching node.

.bat file:

Notice this in .bat file -> **--bootstrap 6024**

```
node.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\bin\appium.js" --address 192.168.1.132 --port 4830 --bootstrap 4830 -U 038d1797094778a8 --nodeconfig D:\MobileBaseProjectRepository\Grid\Node\nodeConfig_192.168.1.132_2.json --session-override
```

so, coming back to your question use **--bootstrap 6024** while invoking appium node, you will through.